Name of a cartoon about an american family
I'm looking for the name of an American animated cartoon that has been broadcasted in France the 90's (and the cartoon didn't look old at the time, so it probably has been created in the 90's as well), and tells the story of an American family. If I had to compare it to some famous animated series, I would say American Dad! or Family Guy.
The things I remember are the following :

both the father and the son are blonde;
in one episode, every kid at school wants to read Shakespeare; one day, the son goes to the bookshop, asks for a book from Shakespeare and the seller complains about everyone wanting Shakespeare books;
in one episode, the only thing the father does is build a fallout shelter and gets obsessed with it;
in another episode, the father gets a neckache, and spends the whole episode (and possibly further episodes as well) with the head bowed at 90°.

I would also be happy if you could give me other clues to find out the name of this cartoon.

I'm French so I maybe watched it, do you remember on which TV channel you watched it? Also, do you remember if there was other family membres? The "drawings" were comparable to American Dad/Family Guy, or more like the Smurfs?

Quite like American Dad. I must have watched it on TF1 or France 3... I guess the son had a mother visible on screen, but I don't remember anything about her.

If it was in the 90ies and in TF1, it may have been on Club Dorothée, here is the list: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_Dorothée#Dessins_animés

It was in the later 90ies, I am too young to have seen Club Dorothée :p !
